# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'No database > selected'

Tags: php, sql-server

Как исправить такой вид ошибки?

> Warning: mysql_connect()
> [function.mysql-connect]: Access
> denied for user
> 'host1326126_panel'@'localhost' (using
> password: YES) in
> Z:\home\localhost\www\config.php on
> line 111
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db() expects
> parameter 2 to be resource, boolean
> given in
> Z:\home\localhost\www\config.php on
> line 112
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
> 'Exception' with message 'No database
> selected' in
> Z:\home\localhost\www\config.php:131
> Stack trace: #0
> Z:\home\localhost\www\config.php(149):
> DB->query('SELECT * FROM `...') #1
> Z:\home\localhost\www\lib\user.lib.php(179):
> DB->fetch_all('SELECT * FROM`...') #2
> Z:\home\localhost\www\lib\user.lib.php(73):
> User->Check_user(NULL, NULL, NULL,
> '11', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '1') #3
> Z:\home\localhost\www\lib\user.lib.php(21):
> User->Insert_user() #4
> Z:\home\localhost\www\lib\user.lib.php(200):
> User->__construct(Object(DB)) #5
> Z:\home\localhost\www\user.php(7):
> require_once('Z:\home\host-ga...') #6
> Z:\home\localhost\www\reg.php(2):
> require_once('Z:\home\host-ga...') #7
> {main} thrown in
> Z:\home\localhost\www\config.php on
> line 131

Comment: Вам строка `Access denied for user ...` ни о чём не говорит, что ли? Все остальные - следствие сочетания её и криворукости программиста, не проверяющего ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

> Access denied for user 'host1326126_panel'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES) in Z:\home\localhost\www\config.php on line 111

**Перевод:**

> *Доступ запрещен для пользователя 'host1326126_panel'@'localhost' (используется ли пароль: да) в файле Z:\home\localhost\www\config.php
>   в строке 111*

Короче, для подключения к MySQL серверу вы используете неправильные данные